# SSIS 2005 package, long in production, succeeded but file half written

Tags: ssis

I have a SQL Server 2005 Standard scheduled job which has been in production for years which executes an SSIS 2005 package using the dtsx file.  The package creates a text file export from a single table.

Last night the job ran successfully, taking the usual time to complete; however, the file generated was only 4 MB instead of the usual 130 MB.  When rerun, the full file was generated.  What could cause the file to stop writing mid-process?

Comment: Maybe some sort of network issue?

Comment: More or less anything could have happened, there is absolutely no way to tell without more information. So your challenge now is to get more details: I would start by looking into every available log that you have (SSIS, SQL Server, Windows) and look for anything unusual around the time that the file was written. But without knowing all the details of the package and your environment it will be extremely hard to say what happened, so in the end you are the best person to find the cause. If you can't find anything, you may need to improve your logging.